# How do you set a variable to the value returned from prompt('...')?

Tags: javascript, variables, user-input

In the code below, when I set the userDoor variable to the prompted user input, the user input attaches to the variable. I know this because the value shows up in the console.log statement just below the variable declaration.

**However**, the variables revealDoor and offerDoor, which are set based on the userInput variable, act wonky in ways that suggest the variable didn't "catch" the value.  (**Wonky**: easier to demonstrate than explain. please run the code below.  UserDoor, revealDoor, and offerDoor should all be different numbers in the range of 1-3. Some of the time, revealDoor === userDoor.  This should never happen. ).

Interestingly, the program works fine when I set userDoor directly to an integer--see commented debug line.

**Why** would the userInput variable show the right value in the console but not seem to catch in the rest of the program?

(This program, by the way, is meant to illustrate the [monty hall paradox](http://www.montyhallproblem.com/)

```js
alert("There are 3 doors.  Behind two of them are DEATH and DOOM.  Behind the other is a BIG TASTY SAUSAGE.");

var yWin = 0;
var yLoss = 0;
var nWin = 0;
var nLoss = 0;


while(true){ //noprotect
  var userDoor = prompt("choose door: 1, 2, or 3");
  //var userDoor = 1 //debug
  console.log('UD: ' + userDoor);


  

  var prizeDoor = randomRange(1,3);
  console.log('PD: ' + prizeDoor);

  var revealDoor = (function(){
    var revealDoor = prizeDoor;
    if (prizeDoor === userDoor) {
      while (revealDoor === prizeDoor) {
        revealDoor = randomRange(1,3);
      }
      return revealDoor;
    }
    else {
      while (revealDoor === prizeDoor || revealDoor === userDoor){
        revealDoor = randomRange(1,3); 
      }
      return revealDoor;
    }
  })();
  console.log('RD: ' + revealDoor);

  var offerDoor = (function(){
    var offerDoor = prizeDoor;
    while(offerDoor === revealDoor || offerDoor === userDoor){
      offerDoor = randomRange(1,3);
    }
    return offerDoor;
  })();
  console.log('OD: ' + offerDoor);

  var choice = prompt("You chose door " + userDoor + ".  Behind door " + revealDoor + ", I reveal DEATH AND DOOM.  I would like to offer you the chance to change your choice to " + offerDoor + ".  Do you accept--y/n?");

  if(choice === "y"){
    userDoor = offerDoor;
  }
  
  var result = (function(){
    var result;
    if(userDoor === prizeDoor){
      alert("YOU FOUND THE PRIZE!");
      result = 'w';
    }
    else {
      alert("You chose DEATH AND DOOM!");
      result = 'l';
    }
    return result;
  })();
  
  
  //Analytics:
  
  switch(result){
    case 'w':
      if(choice === 'y'){
        yWin++;
      }
      else {
        nWin++;
      }
      break;
    case 'l':
      if(choice === 'y'){
        yLoss++;
      }
      else {
        nLoss++;
      }
      break;
  }
             
  var done = prompt("Are you Done?  y/n");
  if(done === "y"){
    break;
  }

}


function randomRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random () * (max - min +1)) + 1;
}

var totalSamples = yWin + nWin + yLoss + nLoss;
var yChoices = yWin + yLoss;
var nChoices = nWin + nLoss;
  
console.log('With a sample set of ' + totalSamples);
console.log('You chose to change ' + (yChoices/nChoices * 100) + '% of the time.');
console.log('When you\'ve chosen to change, you\'ve won ' + (yWin/yChoices * 100) + '% of the time.');
console.log('When you\'ve chosen to stay, you\'ve won ' + (nWin/nChoices * 100) + '% of the time.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that prompt() returns a string.  Which means any '===' comparisons are returning undefined.  I need to convert the returned string to a number using `Number()`.

```
var userDoor = Number(prompt("choose door: 1,2, or 3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userDoor = prompt("choose door: 1,2,       or 3")) * 1
```

Its better 2 use radio button for this

Comment: word.  This works, but the question is "Why would the userInput variable show the right value in the console but not seem to catch in the rest of the program?"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var done = confirm("Are you Done?  y/n");
if (done) break;
```

Instead of d prompt confirmation