# first JS random number to guess game

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have slight problem with my first guessing game, it should draw random number between 1-10, but it return "1" every time. What's wrong in here? Thanks.

```js
function guessGame() {
  let randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  console.log(randomNr)
  let guess;
  do {
    guess = prompt("Guess number 1-10");
    console.log(guess, randomNr);
    if (randomNr > guess) {
      console.log("You guessed too low");
    } else if (randomNr < guess) {
      console.log("Guess was too high");
    }
  } while (guess !== randomNr);
  console.log("You Won");
}

guessGame();
```

Comment: `guess` will never `===` `randomNr` because `guess` is a string and `randomNr` is a number.

Comment: Change `guess = prompt("Guess number 1-10");` to `guess = +prompt("Guess number 1-10");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set a variable to the value returned from prompt('...')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302139/how-do-you-set-a-variable-to-the-value-returned-from-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your random number generator is working correctly. One thing to note though since you define `randomNr` outside of the do while loop it will only create a random number when `guessGame()` if first run, but it won't change the number on each guess. If you would like it to change number after each guess you could move `let randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);` into the do while loop.

Comment: this is not the reason